# How to use .submit() when the event is triggered by code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

In my rails app I have a form in a modal that looks like this:

```
<div id="flag-user-modal" class="modal in" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4>Report user</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Why are you reporting this user?
        <form id="report-user-form" novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form flag" action="/user_users/flag" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
          <div class="form-group hidden flag_user_user_id"><input value="26" class="hidden form-control" type="hidden" name="flag[user_id]" id="flag_user_id"></div>
          <div class="form-group text required flag_reason" aria-required="true">
            <textarea rows="2" class="text required form-control" name="flag[reason]" id="flag_reason" aria-required="true"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-disabler">
          <span class="btn-label">Report</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am submitting it with some jquery:

```
  $('#flag-user-modal #submit').on('click', function() {
    $('#flag-user-modal form').submit();
  });
```

I am validating the form with jquery validate:

```
  $('#report-user-form').validate({
    rules: {
      "flag[reason]": "required"
    }
  });
```

I want to disable the submit button on successful submit and show a loading indicator so users can't keep pressing submit, but I am running into trouble.

```
  $('#report-user-form').on('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('.btn-disabler')append("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse btn-loader'>").disable(true);
    $(this).find('.btn-label').addClass('invisible');
  });
```

I read that .submit() event doesn't fire when it's activated by code.  That may or may not be the problem.  Any ideas on how I can achieve the functionality I want -- to only disable the button and show loading fa-icon on successful submit and not when the jquery validator fails.

Comment: Form submit will reload the page based on whatever `/user_users/flag` does. Your code won't affect button when it reloads. Also makes no sense adding a click handler on submit button to trigger submit...that is default behavior of the button anyway. Also you never check if the form is valid before triggering submit. Can do this with `if($('#flag-user-modal form').valid())` which is a method of the validation plugin

Comment: Hard to help when expectations don't match how a form works. Can store the state on server and disable if you are reloading same page again but even that is not known

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the comments, I was able to find my answer reading a bit into the jquery validation documentation

Comment: @charlietfl Also the reason I have the click handler on submit button to trigger submit is because I'm using a modal and the submit button lies outside the form tags.

Comment: That makes no sense and also doesn't allow user to submit by keyboard.

Comment: @charlietfl I want the submit button in the modal footer, but the input to be in the modal body.  How could I achieve this while keeping it all in the form tag?

Comment: not complicated...wrap modal-body and modal-footer in form. Also button should be in form for proper accessibility like screen readers

Comment: @charlietfl thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into jquery validate I can use a submitHandler option to accomplish what I wanted.

```
  $('#report-user-form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $('#report-user-form').find('.btn-disabler').append("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse btn-loader'>").disable(true);
      $('#report-user-form').find('.btn-label').addClass('invisible');
      form.submit();
    },
    rules: {
      "flag[reason]": "required"
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    validateForm();
});
$('#report-user-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    validateForm();     
});

function validateForm(){
    if($("#flag_reason").val()!=""){
        $('#report-user-form').find('.btn-disabler')append("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse btn-loader'>").disable(true);
        $('#report-user-form').find('.btn-label').addClass('invisible');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you call `validateForm()` twice? And why isn't this incorporated in plugin submitHandler?